# how to drag selected string in uitextview from out of the textview.?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

**iam a beginner in iphone development.
i have one problem in uitextview...wat iam trying to do is dragging the the selected string in uitextview from out of the textview...and drag it to the tabbarcontroller is it possible plz any on help me on this....**this is the code ihave return up to now....plz help me

#

```
import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TabViewController.h"

@class TabBarViewController;

@interface TabBarAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{

    TabBarViewController *txtviewcontroller;
    UITabBarController *tabbar;
    NSArray *viewcontrollerarray;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *viewcontrollerarray;
@property(nonatomic,strong)UITabBarController *tabbar;
@property(nonatomic,retain)TabBarViewController *txtviewcontroller;


@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) TabBarViewController *viewController;

@end
#import "TabBarAppDelegate.h"

#import "TabViewController.h"

@implementation TabBarAppDelegate
@synthesize txtviewcontroller,tabbar,viewcontrollerarray;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
   self.window.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
  self.tabbar=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    txtviewcontroller=[[TabBarViewController alloc]init];
   tabbar.delegate=self;
   viewcontrollerarray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:txtviewcontroller, nil];
    self.tabbar.viewControllers=viewcontrollerarray;


    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[TabBarViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabBarViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[TabBarViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabBarViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabbar;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TabBarViewController : UIViewController
{
     UITextView *textview;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)UITextView *textview;

@end


#import "TabViewController.h"
#import "TabBarAppDelegate.h"
#include <QuartzCore/CoreAnimation.h>

@interface TabBarViewController ()

@end

@implementation TabBarViewController
@synthesize textview;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     self.title=@"firstname";
    CGRect textViewFrame = CGRectMake(20.0f, 20.0f, 280.0f, 124.0f);

    textview = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textViewFrame];
    textview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
   textview.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    textview.editable=NO;
    NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"satyadetails" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *contentString=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    textview.text=contentString;
   textview.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;

    textview.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    textview.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    [self.view addSubview:textview];
enter code here


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. Get event when user touches inside textview (You can get that by `UITextView`'s Delegate (`startEditing` delegate))

Step 2. Add a `UILabel` on ur view giving position where user touches in textview and giving text as that of textview and giving clear color as backgroundcolor. (Do this inside delegate of textview)

Step 3. Inside touches move of ur view change the positions of ur label dynamically according to touches.

Step 4. When user moves its touches till dropping textview delegate will be called check there `if(textview==droppingtextview)` then put `draggingtextview.text=label.text`. and remove label from superview.